# File creation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been reviewing [the tutorial for file management in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) but it doesn't mention how to create a file if one doesn't exist. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to use " f = open('workfile', 'w') " and see if python create the file itself ? I know In some languages this is a normal behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the file in write mode:

```
f = open('fileToWrite.txt', 'w')
```

Note that this will clobber an existing file. The safest approach is to use append mode:

```
f = open('fileToWrite.txt', 'a')
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823854/129655), it's generally better to use a `with` statement to ensure that the file is closed when you have finished with it.

Comment: Right, but even if you use a with statement don't you have to do `f.close()` to close the file?

Comment: @Nathan2055: It's kind of the whole point of `with` that you don't need `f.close()` (or, for other types, `lock.release()`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @jordanm for the edit. I usually do footnote links but I was rushed today.

Answer (score 4):

Just `open` the file in `w` mode, and it will be created it.

If you want to open an existing file if possible, but create a new file otherwise (and don't want to truncate an existing file), read the paragraph in your link that lists the modes. Or, for complete details, see the [`open`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) reference docs. For example, if you want to append to the end instead of overwriting from the start, use `a`.

Answer (score 2):

A new file is only created in write or append modes.

```
open('file', 'w')
```

In shell:

```
$ ls
$ python -c 'open("file", "w")'
$ ls
file
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course.

```
   with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Text in a new file!')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of files you can make. a text and a binary.
to make a text file just use `file = open('(file name and location goes here).txt', 'w')`.
to make a binary file you first `import pickle`, then to put data (like lists numbers ect..) in them you will need to use 'wb' and `pickle.dump(data, file_variable)` to take out you will need to use 'rb' and `pickle.load(file_variable)` and give that a variable becuase that is how you refrence the data.
Here is a exaple:

```
import pickle #bring in pickle
shoplistfile = 'shoplist.data'
shoplist = ['apple', 'peach', 'carrot', 'spice'] #create data
f = open(shoplistfile, 'wb') # the 'wb'
pickle.dump(shoplist, f) #put data in
f.close
del shoplist #delete data
f = open(shoplistfile, 'rb') #open data remember 'rb'
storedlist = pickle.load(f)
print (storedlist) #output
```

note that if such a file exists it will be writen over.